# Symfony2+Doctrine: How to convert iso8859-1 to utf-8 and viceversa?

Tags: php, symfony, encoding, utf-8, doctrine-orm

We're building a Symfony2 app that's using an Oracle database. All the data in the DB is encoded as WE8ISO8859P15 (iso-8859-1), and all the website is encoded as utf-8.

Is there any way to convert all the data received from the database to utf8, and all the data sent to the DB to iso-8859-1, instead of convert the website to iso8859-1? Maybe using a Doctrine event subscriber? If so, which events should I intercept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve a similar problem with a MSSQL instance for convert from utf8 to latin1 and viceversa. I do the following step:

1. Define a custom DBAL Type
2. Initialise on the boot Bundle method (i think you can do in the `config.yml` too)
3. Use it as annotation on the entity field

This his the code:

**DBAL CUSTOM TYPE**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\Type;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class Utf8String extends StringType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $p)
    {
        // convert from utf8 to latin1
        return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $p)
    {
        // convert from latin1 to utf8
        return mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
    }
}
```

**BUNDLE INITIALISATION**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot() {

        if (!Type::hasType('utf8string'))
        {
            Type::addType('utf8string', 'Acme\DemoBundle\Doctrine\Type\Utf8String');

            $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.em_my_sqlserver_entity_manager');
            $conn = $em->getConnection();
            $conn->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('Utf8String', 'utf8string');
        }
    }

}
```

**AN EXAMPLE MAPPED ENTITY**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="VEHICLE")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Vehicle
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="VEHICLE_NAME", type="utf8string", length=16, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID_VEHICLE", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $idVehicle;

....
}
```

Hope this help and hoping you find a better solutions too!!!

Comment: A brilliant idea! Tomorrow I'll try this. Thank you very much!